# Generation of PDF using Docs Template using Zoho Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, zoho

I have created form using Zoho, the responses of which are linked to Google Sheet. The link of google sheet is as below. Once a user submit the form, the data uploaded in google sheet automatically.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bE9RdYs9g3tdawbUzSUz2sG_SknlwfONA9_5MVztJu8/edit?usp=sharing

I have created a template in google docs to generate the PDFs.  the link of Template is as below:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NAU9ZpxxIZko0fy8IltgbZ7Em5IMZKq-JRBge9umYHg/edit

The link of the form is as below:

https://zfrmz.in/iqzvLxSYT6yPvyQwkevD

I have written down the below script to generate the PDF once Zoho Form is submitted.

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
    const info = e.namedValues;
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
    const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 63).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 64).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
    
    sendEmail(e.namedValues ['Email address'][0],pdfFile);
}


function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Daily Transation Summary Report", "Please find the attached DTR", {
    attachments : [pdfFile],
    name: 'My Company'
});

}  
  
function createPDF(info) {
  
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ebglel6vwMGXByeG4wHBBvJu9u0zJeMJ");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ebglel6vwMGXByeG4wHBBvJu9u0zJeMJ");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1kyFimRMdHQZV85F5P6JyCHv1DQ3KJFv1hx5o7lIcNZo");
  
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Name of Person}", info['Name of Person'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Date of Report}", info['Date of Report'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Name of Outlet}", info['Name of Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Opening Petty Cash Balance}", info['Opening Petty Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Received}", info['Total Petty Cash Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Closing Petty Cash Balance}", info['Closing Petty Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Paid}", info['Total Petty Cash Paid'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Available Float Cash Balance}", info['Available Float Cash Balance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Milk For Outlet}", info['Milk For Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Staff Milk/Toast etc.}", info['Staff Milk/Toast etc.'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Petrol Expenses}", info['Petrol Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Water Tank Charges}", info['Water Tank Charges'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Repair And Maintenance}", info['Repair And Maintenance'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Freight Paid}", info['Freight Paid'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Soya Chaap}", info['Purchase of Soya Chaap'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Rumali Roti}", info['Purchase of Rumali Roti'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Purchase of Egg Tray}", info['Purchase of Egg Tray'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Other Expenses}", info['Other Expenses'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Tip Amount (PAYTM & CARD)}", info['Total Tip Amount (PAYTM & CARD)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cash Sales - Outlet}", info['Cash Sales - Outlet'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Cash Sales - KCCO App}", info['Cash Sales - KCCO App'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Card Sales}", info['Card Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Credit (Udhar) Sales}", info['Credit (Udhar) Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Paytm Sales}", info['Paytm Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{KCCO App Sales Razor Pay}", info['KCCO App Sales Razor Pay'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Swiggy Sales}", info['Swiggy Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Zomato Sales}", info['Zomato Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Dunzo Sales}", info['Dunzo Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Zomato Gold Sales}", info['Zomato Gold Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Dine Out Sales}", info['Dine Out Sales'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Cancelled Bill Amount}", info['Total Cancelled Bill Amount'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Sales of the Day (Total of Above)}", info['Total Sales of the Day (Total of Above)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Sales of the Day (As Per PetPooja)}", info['Total Sales of the Day (As Per PetPooja)'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Old Due Receipts  - Cash}", info['Old Due Receipts  - Cash'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Old Due Receipts - Other Modes}", info['Old Due Receipts - Other Modes'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Tip Receipts - Card}", info['Tip Receipts - Card'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Tip Receipts - Paytm}", info['Tip Receipts - Paytm'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 2000}", info['Currency Note of INR 2000'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 500}", info['Currency Note of INR 500'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ Currency Note of INR 200}", info[' Currency Note of INR 200'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 100}", info['Currency Note of INR 100'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 50}", info['Currency Note of INR 50'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 20}", info['Currency Note of INR 20'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Currency Note of INR 10}", info['Currency Note of INR 10'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Other Currency Note/Coins}", info['Other Currency Note/Coins'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Available Cash to Handover}", info['Total Available Cash to Handover'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Credit Approval By// Bill No// Total Amount of Credit", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Credit Approval By// Bill No// Total Amount of Credit'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Bills of Credit Recovery}", info['Total No. of Bills of Credit Recovery'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Mode of Payment// Bill No// Total Amount Received}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Mode of Payment// Bill No// Total Amount Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Complementary Bills  During the Day}", info['Total No. of Complementary Bills  During the Day'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No//Reason// Bill No//Amount Settled}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No//Reason// Bill No//Amount Settled'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{Total No. of Cancelled Bills During the Day}", info['Total No. of Cancelled Bills During the Day'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Bill No// Bill Amount}", info['S.No.//Name of Person// Mobile No// Bill No// Bill Amount'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{S.No.// Bill No// Mode of Payment//Tip Amount Received}", info['S.No.// Bill No// Mode of Payment//Tip Amount Received'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{No. of Cylinders Received at Outlet}", info['No. of Cylinders Received at Outlet'][0]); 
  
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name of Outlet'][0]+ " " + info['Date of Report'][0]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
    
  return pdfFile;
  
}
```

Comment: Upon further checking the `afterFormSubmit(e)` does not exist as [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder). What error do you get when running your Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SUGGESTION:

Since you're using a third-party form (Zoho forms) that sends data to your Google Sheet file, it seems like the `afterFormSubmit` or the `onFormSubmit` will unfortunately not work in your setup. However, as discussed, you may want to check this sample tweaked script below on a [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) trigger as a workaround:

> In this workaround, I have added an identifier on Column `CC`, where the code adds a value on last row of `CC` column with "Done", indicating that the data has already been sent via email. This way, every time the `time driven` trigger kicks in, it won't resend the same data all the time but only new last row that do not have "Done" yet on row `CC`.

### SCRIPT - *updated*

```
function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Daily Transation Summary Report", "Please find the attached DTR", {
    attachments : [pdfFile],
    name: 'My Company'
});

}

function afterFormSubmit() { // Add this function to a time driven trigger
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DTR - Final Response");
  var lastRow = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var emailCheck = ss.getRange("CC"+lastRow);
  const info = ss.getRange("A"+lastRow+":CB"+lastRow).getValues(); //Get the last submitted row data from the DTR - Final Response.
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const entryRow = ws.getLastRow() + 1;

  if(emailCheck.getValue()!= "Done"){ // checks if the last row with data on DTR - Final Response sheet on CC column has 'Done" value or not
    const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
    sendEmail(info[0][78],pdfFile);
    emailCheck.setValue("Done"); //Set value on CC column of the data row that has been submitted via email with "Done" indication that it has already been sent via email
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 63).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
    ws.getRange(entryRow, 64).setValue(pdfFile.getName());
    Logger.log("PDF sent to email: "+ info[0][78])
  }else{
    Logger.log("This data has already been sent with PDF name: "+info[0][3]+ " " + info[0][2])
    return; //if current row data on CC column has "Done" value it means it was already send via email, so it will be ignored.
  }
    
}

function createPDF(info) {
  
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1lxR27p9zVQi416j3Lq2ZRsLGb0xcdQ1a");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1VaIeCeN6RlqACSXg_MGT7BRa5cyPMpbN");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1Stvxgn76qxti40EeRzgS3UlQJ94Dh9oldYVhfCHUnMY");
  
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();

  // made some test on my end to a few data
  body.replaceText("{Name of Person}", info[0][4]);
  body.replaceText("{Date of Report}", info[0][2]);
  body.replaceText("{Outlet}", info[0][3]);
  body.replaceText("{Opening Petty Cash Balance}", info[0][57]);
  body.replaceText("{Total Petty Cash Received from H.O.}", info[0][24]);
  body.replaceText("{Closing Petty Cash Balance}", info[0][28]);
  // made some test on my end to a few data

  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  
  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info[0][3]+ " " + info[0][2]);
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
    
  return pdfFile;
  
}
```

### Quick Test Result

> **Sample last row data (the most recent submitted data from Zoho form) to be used on `DTR - Final Response` sheet:**

[image]

> **Added the `afterFormSubmit` function to a `time-driven trigger` (in my testing-it, will run every minute):**

[image]

> **PDF was sent via email to my test email account added on the last row**

[image]

[image]

[image]

> **Then the PDF URL and and PDF file name was posted on `Sheet 2` columns 63 & 64 on the last row data.**

[image]

> **Time-Driven trigger logs from the Apps Script Editor:**

[image]

Comment: I have moved all the data of form submission to "DTR - Final Response". The email ID is linked in "DTR - Final Response" sheet and I have installed trigger also in that. I want to send PDF to email id once form is submitted.

Comment: Could you please guide..

Comment: I see, since you want to send the PDF to an email ID once form is submitted, then my apologies as it won't be possible because Zoho form submission to Google Sheet will not trigger the `afterFormSubmit` or `onFormSubmit` based on my several testing.

Comment: Any other trigger we can use... Like time driven to send email.

Comment: Any other trigger we can use... Like time driven to send email .

Comment: Yes, I think time driven trigger will work but it has to be controlled to only send email if there are recently new submitted data from Zoho forms.

Comment: Can you help in it.

Comment: Yes let's see what I can I help...

Comment: I have updated my sample script with the implementation that I can think of using time-driven trigger.

Comment: showing this error Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient
    at sendEmail(Code:2:14)
    at afterFormSubmit(Code:18:5)

Comment: I have updated the `afterFormSubmit` script, hopefully it will work this time on your end

Comment: Thanks Its worked

Comment: @Admin-RKPareekCo You're welcome & I'm glad it works on your end. If you don't mind, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.